# How to draw circle in cocos2dx

Tags: android, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

How to draw circle or line in cocos2dx 3.0.

my code is

```
DrawNode *drawnode = DrawNode::create();
drawnode->drawDot(ccp(15,Director::sharedDirector()->getVisibleSize().height/2),50,Color4F(255,255,255,255));

this->addChild(drawnode);
```

Comment: explain what isn't working with this code

Comment: draw circle is not visible on layer....i don't know...this code is working or not.....

plz give me solution...and other function like drawPolygon and more drawing function also not working...

Thanks

Comment: i believe color4f should be 1,1,1,1 not 255..

Comment: Thanx..its work fine but i want transparent circle..now its fill with white color and also i want to change border color

Comment: the last value is the alpha channel, if you want to have a transparent white circle you can put `Color4F(1,1,1,0.5)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

to draw a line cocos2d-x has function
drawsegment

a circle is special type of polygon
so for circle drawpolygon function is used

// for line

```
 draw->drawSegment(startPoint, moved, 5,Color4F(1,222,120,1) );
```

// for circle

```
static CCPoint Circle [nCount]; // vertex array
for ( int i = 0 ; i <nCount; i ++) {
    float rads = i * coef; // radians
    Circle [i] .x = Radius * cosf (rads); //vertex x
    Circle [i] .y = Radius * sinf (rads); //vertex y
}
draw-> drawPolygon (Circle, nCount, blue, 0 , red);
```

Comment: I wish I could figure out the values for nCount, coef and Radius

Comment: nCount is number of vertices you want in polygon, you can keep it to 150 or something like that
coef is the angle between two adjacent vertices and center
take its value with respect to nCount
like, 2.0f * ( float ) M_PI / nCount